# What will happen if I change the privacy of a photo from "Friends" to "Public"?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy, facebook-notifications

I uploaded a picture to my timeline and set the privacy to "Friends". My friends received notifications. But now I have changed the privacy of the image to public. Will my friends get new notifications or what will happen?

Answer (score 4):

New notifications will not be sent to your friends about the changes you make in privacy settings.

Answer (score 1):

*My friends received notifications.*

This notification was not about your privacy, it must be a notification about that you have added new photo. So when you change your privacy from *Friends* to *Public*, your friends will not get notify about this but now everyone on Facebook (whom you have not blocked) will able to see your this pic as you have set audience public.

Comment: So the trick is to post the photo with "Only me" as able to view.
Then once the photo has been posted, change the photo permission to Friends or Public. That permission change will then NOT result in a notification to Friends, right ?